# Convergence of functions of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence

I know that

> IF $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables that converges to $X$ *almost surely*, then for any continuous function $g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}\ ,\ g(X_n) $ converges to $g(X)$ *almost surely*.

Now if I replace *almost surely* with *in probability*, the statement still holds.

My question:

Does the statement hold for convergence *in law*?

Comment: You also asked here... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949270/convergence-of-functions-of-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment4001932_1949270